# Расположить кнопки друг за другом в ряд

Tags: android, java

Вроде бы элементарная задача, но я не могу с ней справиться.
Создаю нное количество кнопок, допустим 10. Мне нужно, чтобы они шли друг за другом. Если не вмещаются в одну строку - кнопка переносится на другую. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"

    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="privet"
    />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Если orientation="horizontal", то кнопки уходят за границу активити, если  orientation="vertical" то кнопки располагаются одна под другой.

Answer (score 3):

Стандартный элемент этого не умеет. Используйте gridview или несколько layout'ов (как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265480/displaying-the-childs-of-a-linear-layout-in-multiple-lines) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958767/dynamically-display-imageview-with-multi-line-linear-layout)).

Comment: [или здесь на русском][1]


  [1]: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/116-urok-57-gridview-i-ego-atributy

Comment: Текст в кнопке может быть разной длинны, там строгая сетка получается, если использвать GridLayout, и если текст будет длинней, чем ширина кнопки, то часть кнопки наложится на другую. С этим как-то можно бороться?

Comment: Также количество кнопок может быть разное. Возможно ли динамически создавать кнопки и леяуты? Допустим создал леяут, добавил на него 3 кнопки, добавил этот леяут на активити, затем опять создал леяут, добавил еще 3 кнопки и т д?

Comment: > Возможно ли динамически создавать кнопки и леяуты?

да, конечно.

это один из правильных способов решения этой задачи.